# Maximum element after M operations

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given are the 3 elements N1,N2,N3

Now we can perform operation on these elements.

Operation is as follow :

In a single operation,we will choose a particular element and decrease the value of elements to half (i.e. if initial value of element is x, then after decrement it will be x/2 where division is integer division, e.g. 3/2=1 and 4/2=2). Meanwhile, the value of other two elements will increase by one.

Now we need to minimise the maximum element if we can perform this operation for ATMOST M seconds and each second we can perform this operation atmost once.

**Example  :** Let N1=1 , N2=2 , N3=3 , M=1 Then here answer is 3

**Explanation :** We can pick the 3rd element and make it half. Note that first and second element will increase by 1 units. So the values become 2,3,1. Maximum of these values is 3. Hence answer is 3.

**My Approach :** Every time pick up the largest element and it decrease by half and increase other two by +1.

**Code :**

```
long long  ans=max(N1,max(N2,N3));
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){       
    if(N1>=N2 && N1>=N3){
        N1/=2;
        N2++;
        N3++;   
    }
    else if(N2>=N1 && N2>=N3){
        N2/=2;
        N1++;
        N3++;   
    }
    else{
        N1++;
        N2++;
        N3/=2;  
    }
    ans=min(ans,max(N1,max(N2,N3)));
}
```

**Failure :** 
But let N1=8 , N2=8 , N3=4 , M=3 then answer is 5 and this approach goes wrong as according to mentioned algorithm steps would have been :

```
8 8 4 -> 4 9 5 -> 5 4 6 ->  6 5 3
```

But correct one is :

```
8 8 4 -> 9 9 2 -> 4 10 3 -> 5 5 4
```

**Constraints :** M is between 1 and 100 . N1 , N2  and N3 can go upto 10^9.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat What you mean by reachable search space ?I didn't get your question.And obviously N1,N2 and N3 are not independent as they are affected by operation on other two

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Its going to be 3^100 right?And obviously we dont have so much search space

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Then ?Please explain a bit more

Comment: @DavidEisenstat If its 10^7 then it can be done within limits.But how are you guessing this ?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Oh i see..

Comment: Better known as the running contest problem [PRPOTION](http://www.codechef.com/OCT14/problems/PRPOTION).

Comment: Since you say an operation can be done "at most once" per minute - can we solve your example, where N1=1 , N2=2 , N3=3 , M=1, by doing no operation at all?